# Can someone explain how Production and Development work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, release, development-environment, production-environment

I wonder how development and production work when you release website. How you work on development and send it to production when using ASP .NET Core in Visual Studio.

This is folder published on IIS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdZaX.png)

This is folder with source code on localhost:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyJHh.png)

Answer (score 0):

To quote the official words, whenever a user accesses an ASP.NET application, his browser will send a request to the website. The request is received by the Web server software, which coordinates with the ASP.NET runtime to generate and return the content of the requested resource. The ASP.NET Development Server is an alternative web server option for the development environment; it ships with and is integrated into Visual Studio. Unless the web application has been configured to use IIS, the ASP.NET Development Server is automatically started and used as the web server the first time you visit a web page from within Visual Studio. The demo web applications we created back in the [Determining What Files Need to Be Deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/determining-what-files-need-to-be-deployed-cs) tutorial were both file system-based web applications that were not configured to use IIS. Therefore , when visiting either of these websites from within Visual Studio the ASP.NET Development Server is used.

For more information, refer to the official document：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/core-differences-between-iis-and-the-asp-net-development-server-cs